# converting IP to binarry and convert back to string

Tags: c#

i want to convert both ipv4 and ipv6 addresses to binary and back to string.

for example 192.168.1.1 to 11000000.10101000.00000001.00000001 and also 11000000.10101000.00000001.00000001 to 192.168.1.1

i found this post: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505543/convert-and-display-ip-address-to-binary-form) but its just work for ipv4.

i also found this one: [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14499482/converting-ip-to-byte-convert-back-to-string) so i tried this:

```
IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.1");
textBox1.Text = ip.GetAddressBytes().ToString();
```

but it displays System.Byte[] in the textbox.

long story short i want to use the stable converting method which work in both ipv4 and ipv6.(a dll could be greate.)

thank you.

Comment: What does `textBox1.Text = string.Join(".", ip.GetAddressBytes().Select(b => Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')));` do?

Comment: thank you. but as i think its just work for ipv4. and how can i convert it back?

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to do since `11000000.10101000.00000001.00000001` isn't binary - it's a string containing 1s, 0s and *dots*.

Comment: yes. i mean binary string. my bad. sorry.

Comment: You can't just call `ToString()` on an array and expect something other than the default to come out. You need to format each element as a string and join the results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert to binary:

```
var address = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.1");
var bytes = address
    .GetAddressBytes()
    .Select(number => Convert.ToString(number, 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));
var binaryAddress = string.Join(".", bytes);
// => 11000000.10101000.00000001.00000001
```

And to convert back:

```
var bytes = binaryAddress
    .Split('.')
    .Select(@byte => Convert.ToInt32(@byte, 2));
var address = IPAddress.Parse(string.Join(".", bytes));
// => 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: Whops. I forgot the second part of the question. 2 seconds.

Comment: thank you so much. it works just fine. but how can convert it back to string?

Comment: @Dan Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.1");
textbox1.Text = ip.GetAddressBytes().Select(x => x.ToString()).Aggregate((x,y) => x + y);
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: thanks. but the output is: 19216811. it just remove the dots!

Comment: Why `Aggregate` instead of String.Join? Aggregate will create a lot of temporary strings for no reason. This code doesn't use any delimiters either. You *can* pass a StringBuilder object to  `Aggregate` so you can `Append` the formatted strings

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution :
Make Two Functions so that it remains generic you can use further as well
**This Method is used to convert string to binary :**

**public static string StringToBinary(string ip)**
{

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (char c in ip.ToCharArray())
 {

sb.Append(Convert.ToString(c, 2).PadLeft(8,'0'));

}

return sb.ToString();

}

This Method Is used to convert binary to string  :

**public static string BinaryToString(string ip)**
{

List byteList = new List();

for (int i = 0; i < ip.Length; i += 8)
 {

byteList.Add(Convert.ToByte(ip.Substring(i, 8), 2));

}

return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteList.ToArray());

}

Now use it,

**IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.1");**

**//To Binary**

**textBox1.Text =  StringToBinary(ip.GetAddressBytes().ToString());**

**//To String**

**textBox1.Text =   BinaryToString(ip.GetAddressBytes().ToString());**